# Grails spring switch user

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.4

I have problem with `j_spring_security_switch_user`, as I only can switch between users with the role `ROLE_SWITCH_USER`.

Can I change it so it can switch to users with the `ROLE_USER` from a user with the role `ROLE_SWITCH_USER`?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correct then you want to switch to only those users who have `ROLE_USER` role?

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep the permission rule for switching user, so it's only can be done from ROLE_SWITCH_USER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed by:

Create file MySwichUserFilter.groovy:

```
class MySwichUserFilter extends SwitchUserFilter {

    protected Authentication attemptSwitchUser(HttpServletRequest request) throws AuthenticationException {

        Authentication switchTo = super.attemptSwitchUser(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        return switchTo;
    }
}
```

Correct the resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    ...
    switchUserProcessingFilter(MySwichUserFilter){
        userDetailsService  = ref('userDetailsService')
        switchUserUrl       = "/j_spring_security_switch_user"
        exitUserUrl         = "/j_spring_security_exit_user"
        targetUrl           = conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
    }
    ...
}
```